# How to convert microsecond timestamp to readable date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp

I want to convert the following timestamp - `"1571299045371875"` which is in microseconds to a date format of `"2019-10-17T07:57:35.333333Z"`.

I've tried using:

```
date_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
st = date_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

But this gives me `[Errno 22] Invalid argument`, when trying to convert the timestamp.
Converting a timestamp of milliseconds works fine, but I can't lose precision.

Is there any way to convert microsecond timestamp?

Comment: it seems you want the output to resemble UTC, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert microseconds to seconds, then you can use `fromtimestamp()` to convert seconds since the UNIX epoch to a `datetime` object.

```
import datetime
timestamp_microseconds = 1571299045371875
timestamp_seconds = timestamp_microseconds/1000000
dobj = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_seconds)
print(dobj.isoformat())
```

---

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 17, 16, 57, 25, 371875)
>>> '2019-10-17T16:57:25.371875'
```

As mentioned by @MrFuppes this will return a `datetime` object based on the machine's local time.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

> *`classmethod`* `datetime.fromtimestamp(`*`timestamp, tz=None`*`)`  
> Return the local date and time corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by `time.time()`. If optional argument *`tz`* is `None` or not specified, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date and time, and the returned `datetime` object is naive.

Comment: @MrFuppes, Yes I use datetime.utcfromtimestamp for that, but this helped me realise I don't need to pass in microseconds as a parameter to get microseconds out.

Answer (score 1):

given your expected output, you should use a datetime object that resembles UTC:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

ts = 1571299045371875
dtobj = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts/1e6, tz=timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 17, 7, 57, 25, 371875, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

isostring = dtobj.isoformat()
# '2019-10-17T07:57:25.371875+00:00'

# or as specified in the question
isostring = dtobj.isoformat().replace('+00:00', 'Z')
# '2019-10-17T07:57:25.371875Z'
```