# What time format is this? I don't think it's unix timestamp

Tags: python

Hello I'm coding a script to fetch creation dates of specific profiles on a platform what time format is this?

> 1396752197709867

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks a lot like epoch to me: https://www.epochconverter.com/ you can convert it to a human date here too

Comment: Yes, according to epochconverter:
"Assuming that this timestamp is in microseconds (1/1,000,000 second):
GMT: Sunday 6 April 2014 02:43:17.709"

Answer (score 0):

If it's microseconds then you can convert them to seconds, and use [`fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) to convert seconds since the UNIX epoch to a `datetime` object.

This is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62654898/355230) to the question [How to convert microsecond timestamp to readable date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654855/how-to-convert-microsecond-timestamp-to-readable-date)

```
import datetime

timestamp_microseconds = 1396752197709867
timestamp_seconds = timestamp_microseconds/1000000
dobj = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_seconds)
print(dobj.isoformat())  # -> 2014-04-05T19:43:17.709867
```